# Was there a change in the theme in the main page?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, ignored-tags, tag-watching

I noticed now that when I land on the main page, questions with tags that I have marked as "watched" are no longer "highlighted" with a different background color, and all questions now show with a white background:
[image]

The questions with a watched tag used to show with a background as in the following screen-shot, from the "Questions" page:
[image]

Was this a recent change? I don't like it; I liked having the highlight in the main page. Can it be changed back?

---

**Addendum.** As of this morning (June 14th, 11am CDT) the different background on watched tags is back on the main page.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366321/ignored-and-watched-tags-seem-broken

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks! That answers it. They broke it, they plan to fix  it.

Comment: Yeah. This came up on Meta MathOverflow earlier today.

Comment: I can't imagine why anyone would downvote this. In any case, glad it got resolved.

Comment: @Yorch Downvotes on meta represent disagreement; so in this case it would be disagreement with my  request that it be changed back. Diff'rent strokes, I guess.

Comment: @Arturo: I suppose one can also interpret the downvote as "I think you should have asked this on meta.SE instead", but that's only a speculation. (My point is that it's not just plain disagreement.)

Comment: @Yorch, my pet peeve with this voting system is that those of us with low reputation don't get to see the actual votes.  An item that's was asked a few days ago could have a score of +1 and we might skip over it because it's obviously not very interesting. Yet it actually has a score of +25 -24, and is very interesting. And even those of you with large reputations have to go out of your way to see both values. ¶ I really don't understand why both values aren't always displayed by default, for everyone to see, at least on the meta sites.